# Reformating input data

Tags: r

I have a data with two columns (edge file) with representing vertex ids and there connections as

```
v1,v2

23732,23778

23732,23871

23732,58098

23778,23824

23778,23871

23778,58098

23871,58009

23871,58098

58009,58098

58098,58256
```

I need to reformat it, i.e. vertex ids need to be consecutive and starting with one like this

```
v1,v2

1,2

1,3

1,4

2,5

2,3

2,4

3,5

3,4

5,4

4,6
```

Can anyone suggest how to do it automatically? 
Also, I would need conversion table with both original and new ids.
Your support is appreciated.

Comment: Can you `dput()` part of your data so we can reproduce it easier?

Comment: `m[order(m[,1],m[,2]),]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach which uses `factor()` for renumbering:

```
library(data.table)
# reshape from wide to long format using row  numbers
tmp <- melt(setDT(DT)[, rn := .I], "rn", value.name = "old")[
  # create new ids from factor levels
  , new := as.integer(factor(old))][]

# reshape back to wide format again
dcast(tmp, rn ~ variable, value.var = "new")[, -"rn"]
```

> ```
>     v1 v2
>  1:  1  2
>  2:  1  4
>  3:  1  6
>  4:  2  3
>  5:  2  4
>  6:  2  6
>  7:  4  5
>  8:  4  6
>  9:  5  6
> 10:  6  7
> ```

The translation table can be created by

```
tmp[, unique(.SD), .SDcols = c("old", "new")]
```

> ```
>      old new
> 1: 23732   1
> 2: 23778   2
> 3: 23871   4
> 4: 58009   5
> 5: 58098   6
> 6: 23824   3
> 7: 58256   7
> ```

---

In order to reproduce *exactly* OP's new id numbering we need to rearrange factor levels using the `fct_inorder()` function from the `forcats` package:

```
tmp <- melt(DT[, rn := .I], "rn", value.name = "old")[
  order(rn, variable), new := as.integer(forcats::fct_inorder(factor(old)))][]
dcast(tmp, rn ~ variable, value.var = "new")[, -"rn"]
```

> ```
>     v1 v2
>  1:  1  2
>  2:  1  3
>  3:  1  4
>  4:  2  5
>  5:  2  3
>  6:  2  4
>  7:  3  6
>  8:  3  4
>  9:  6  4
> 10:  4  7
> ```

Then, the translation becomes

> ```
>      old new
> 1: 23732   1
> 2: 23778   2
> 3: 23871   3
> 4: 58009   6
> 5: 58098   4
> 6: 23824   5
> 7: 58256   7
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(
  "v1,v2
23732,23778
23732,23871
23732,58098
23778,23824
23778,23871
23778,58098
23871,58009
23871,58098
58009,58098
58098,58256"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite what you asked for, as I sorted the node names before assigning IDs.

What I chose to do is get all of the unique node IDs, sort them, and assign them each to an integer.

```
df <- structure(list(v1 = c(23732L, 23732L, 23732L, 23778L, 23778L, 
    23778L, 23871L, 23871L, 58009L, 58098L), v2 = c(23778L, 23871L, 
    58098L, 23824L, 23871L, 58098L, 58009L, 58098L, 58098L, 58256L
    )), .Names = c("v1", "v2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -10L))

# Put nodes in ascending order
df <- df[order(df$v1, df$v2), ]

# create a mapping of node number to node ID (as a vector)
# All unique nodes between the two columns, sorted
node_names <- sort(unique(c(df$v1, df$v2)))
# a vector of integers from 1 to length(node_names)
node_id <- seq_along(node_names)
# assign (map) the node names to the integer values
names(node_id) <- node_names

# Add the node IDs to df
df$v1_id <- node_id[as.character(df$v1)]
df$v2_id <- node_id[as.character(df$v2)]
df

      v1    v2 v1_id v2_id
1  23732 23778     1     2
2  23732 23871     1     4
3  23732 58098     1     6
4  23778 23824     2     3
5  23778 23871     2     4
6  23778 58098     2     6
7  23871 58009     4     5
8  23871 58098     4     6
9  58009 58098     5     6
10 58098 58256     6     7
```